# HowTo get access to structure elements using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

Problem is to create a `std::vector` data table (`struct MegaTable`, from the example below), where items (`struct DataItem`, from the example below) could have a pointer to the whole data array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>

struct MegaDataItem;

struct DataItem 
{
     int            a_;
     char*          ch_;

     MegaDataItem*  ptr_;

     DataItem( int _a, char* _ch, MegaDataItem* ptr )
          : a_( _a )
          , ch_( _ch )
          , ptr_( ptr )
     {}
};
typedef std::vector< DataItem > DataTable;


struct MegaDataItem 
{
     int            b_;
     DataTable      data_;

     MegaDataItem( int _b )
          : b_( _b )
     {
          for ( int j = 15; j >= 10; j-- )
          {
               DataItem item( j, "", this );
               data_.push_back( item );
          }
     }
};
typedef std::vector< MegaDataItem > MegaTable;


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
     MegaTable table;

     for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
     {
          MegaDataItem megaItem( i );
          table.push_back( megaItem );
     }
     return 0;
}
```

And debug snapshot from MSVS:

[image]

As you can see, `ptr_` pointer everywhere equals to **0x0031fccc**, but that is not correct! Pointer must consists with correct `struct MegaDataItem` data, where all `struct DataItem`'s exists...

Thanks for the help!

PS. I know that this is not the hard question, but I can't get it, how to get this things work!

---

**UPDATE** (corrected solution):
PS: thnks to jpalecek! :)

```
MegaDataItem( const MegaDataItem& other )
          : b_( other.b_ )
     {
          data_.clear();
          DataTable::const_iterator d_i( other.data_.begin() ), d_e( other.data_.end() );
          for ( ; d_i != d_e; ++d_i )
               data_.push_back( DataItem( (*d_i).a_, (*d_i).ch_, this ) );
     }

void operator=( const MegaDataItem& other )
     {
          b_ = other.b_;

          data_.clear();
          DataTable::const_iterator d_i( other.data_.begin() ), d_e( other.data_.end() );
          for ( ; d_i != d_e; ++d_i )
               data_.push_back( DataItem( (*d_i).a_, (*d_i).ch_, this ) );
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `MegaDataItem` structure is not copyable and assignable (if you copy or assign the `vector` in `MegaDataItem`, the back pointers will point to the original `MegaDataItem`, which is incorrect). You have to amend that.

Particularly, you'll have to implement the copy-constructor and assignment operator. In these, you have to redirect the `ptr_` pointers in `DataItem`s to the new `MegaDataItem`.

Example implementation:

```
MegaDataItem(const MegaDataItem& other) : b_(other.b_) {
  // fill data
  for(DataItem& item : other.data_)
    data_.push_back(DataItem(item.a_, item.ch_, this));
}

operator=(const MegaDataItem& other) {
  b_=other.b_;
  data_.clear();
  for(DataItem& item : other.data_)
    data_.push_back(DataItem(item.a_, item.ch_, this));
}
```

BTW, depending on what `ch_` in `DataItem` means, you may want to implement these in `DataItem`, too.

Comment: Thnks for the reply! And how to do this? I mean, I know that I have to re implement copy-contructor & operator[], but how?

Comment: See edit. Note this is just an example, it could be implemented otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, it seems to be working as intended. You're passing `this` to `DataItem`'s constructor, so of course all the `DataItem`s created by a `MegaDataItem` will share the same `ptr_` value.